# PIMcore installation issues via Docker

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose, pimcore

I'm having permission problems installing PIMcore on Windows

I'm trying to install PIMcore via Docker, but when I try this command:

> "docker compose exec php vendor/bin/pimcore-install --mysql-host-socket=db --mysql-username=pimcore --mysql-password=pimcore --mysql-database=pimcore"

I'm prompted to enter the admin username and password, after which I get this error:

> Cannot rename "/tmp/database.yamlrnaQGd" to "/var/www/html/config/local/database.yaml": rename(/tmp/database.yamlrnaQGd,/var/www/html/config/local/database.yaml): Permission denied

I'm following these steps: https://github.com/pimcore/demo

What could be the reason for this error? How can I fix that?

Sorry for my bad english.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This issue with permission. Did you changed user for php in `docker-compose` file? You can run

```
sed -i "s|#user: '1000:1000'|user: '$(id -u):$(id -g)'|g" docker-compose.yaml
```

if this won't fix yours issue, you can change permission on `var`/`config` dir